# connect three coding sequences with IRES

Tags: molecular-biology

To express two proteins at once in mammalian cells, expression vectors carrying an IRES (internal ribosomal entry site) are available. Does anyone know any attempt to express three proteins using two IRESs or more. The third gene may be expressed very low, but it may be acceptable depending on experiments if it works.

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14667529 :: https://www.abmgood.com/Bicistronic-Tricistronic-Promoter-Lentivirus.html ::
Let me know if this helps!

Comment: @Kendall Thank you, the information was useful.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the Foot and Mouth Disease [2A Peptide](http://www.nature.com/gt/journal/v11/n23/full/3302361a.html), a self-cleaving peptide sequence that can be inserted in between two proteins. The proteins are translated as one sequence, but cleaved at the 2A peptide to form 2 proteins. If I'm reading the source right, they used 4 genes in a row with 2A peptides between them. The 2A peptide has the advantage of being much smaller than most IRES elements, while being more reliable than IRES or internal promoters.

Comment: Thank you. I asked this question out of curiosity. But you are right. 2A peptide could be convenient to this purpose.